How to remove the empty box before the 1st subtitle in a tcolorbox without a title?
I want to make a tcolorbox without a title but with subtitles.
However, there is empty box before the first subtitle. How can I remove it?


\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        notitle,
        toptitle=1mm,
        bottomtitle=2mm,
        width=\textwidth,
        center,
        parbox=false,
        sharp corners=all,
        colback=white,
        colframe=black,
        boxrule=0.3mm,
        subtitle style={colback=white,coltext=black,bottomrule=0pt},
        colbacktitle=lightgray,
        coltitle=black]%
            
        \tcbsubtitle{test}
        \lipsum[1]
                
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}          


The vertical space OP wants to drop is the inner top space of a tcolorbox, which has the height of /tcb/boxsep + /tcb/top. By default, that is 1mm + 2mm = 3mm.
If there's always a beginning \tcbsubtitle in the upper part, then you can set top=-1mm for the tcolorbox so that the accumulated inner top space is zero.
Otherwise, it seems you has to use a special /tcb/before setting for the beginning \tcbsubtitle.
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins} % for debugging option "/tcb/draft"

\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{
  every box/.append style={
    notitle,
    toptitle=1mm,
    bottomtitle=2mm,
    width=\textwidth,
    center,
    parbox=false,
    sharp corners=all,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black,
    boxrule=0.3mm,
    subtitle style={colback=white,coltext=black,bottomrule=0pt},
    colbacktitle=lightgray,
    coltitle=black,
  }
}

\begin{document}

Original
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \tcbsubtitle{test}
  \lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

Showing the cause of extra space above \verb|\tcbsubtitle|
\begin{tcolorbox}[draft]
  \tcbsubtitle[frame empty, interior empty]{test}
  \lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

Workaround 1: setting \verb|/tcb/top=-<value of /tcb/boxsep>|
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=-1mm]
  \tcbsubtitle[toprule=0pt]{test}
  \lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

Workaround 2: negative before skip for \verb|\tcbsubtitle|
\begin{tcolorbox}
  \tcbsubtitle[toprule=0pt, before={\par\vskip-3mm\noindent}]{test}
  \lipsum[1][1-5]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}


